# How to get debug info from loaded DLL?

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, dll, sentry

I use Unity to develop game.

I build a DLL for some scripts to hotfix. Here is how load the dll in the script

```
    AssetBundleBoot.mainAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(dll.bytes);
```

In the same time, I use Sentry to collect crash log. The core code

```
var e = new Event(type);
var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(4, true);
if (trace.FrameCount > 0) {
        var firstFrame = trace.GetFrame(0);
        e.message = logString + ": " + firstFrame;
        var frames = fsData.CreateList(trace.FrameCount);
        var framesList = frames.AsList;
        for (var i = 0; i < trace.FrameCount; ++i) {
                var f = trace.GetFrame(i);
                var frame = fsData.CreateDictionary();
                var frameDict = frame.AsDictionary;
                frameDict["filename"] = new fsData(f.GetFileName() ?? "");
                frameDict["function"] = new fsData(f.GetMethod().ToString());
                frameDict["lineno"] = new fsData(f.GetFileLineNumber());
                framesList.Add(frame);
        }
        var st = fsData.CreateDictionary();
        st.AsDictionary["frames"] = frames;
        e["stacktrace"] = st;
} else {
        e.message = logString + " " + stackTrace;
        e.SetExtra("stacktrace", new fsData(stackTrace));
}
```

I find if code in dll crash sentry will get the stacktrace without line number like this:

```
Boolean MoveNext() at line 0
Void LogError(System.Object) at line 0
Void Log(LogType, System.Object) at line 0
Void LogFormat(LogType, UnityEngine.Object, System.String, System.Object[]) at line 0
```

I try to build the dll with debug+ and get the mdb file. I search google, find a lot of blogs tell me how to debug dll in IDE using mdb file, but I still don't know how to get debug info in runtime when the dll crash.

So how to let sentry get stacktrace with line number(or verbose stacktrace)

BTW, Unity can build development build with "Development Build" in the right bottom of screen. How to build a player with debug info without "Development Build".